# Sort function not working as expected in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Im rearranging int array such that all negatives are at right side and all positive and zeros at left side of array,
without changing the order of positive element and negative elements in given array.

**For example:-**

**n**=18

**given input**: 34 99 40 70 -28 27 -49 96 -18 -90 -6 -2 92 82 53 -47 -98 -53

**expected output**: 34 99 40 70 27 96 92 82 53 -28 -49 -18 -90 -6 -2 -47 -98 -53

**my output**: 99 40 70 34 27 96 53 82 92 -53 -98 -47 -2 -6 -90 -18 -49 -28 
-84

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool comp(int a,int b){
    if((a>=0 && b>=0) || (a<0 && b<0)|| (a<0 && b>=0)) return false;
    if(a>=0 && b<0) return true;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)cin>>a[j];
    sort(a,a+n,comp);
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)cout<<a[j]<<" ";
return 0;
}
```

why it isn't rearranging as expected? I couldn't find any errors.

Comment: "`int a[n];`" Doesn't have something like variable length arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: can't we perform this operation(sorting/rearranging) on arrays also?

Comment: Yes, but an array with a size that is not a compile time constant is not valid C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `comp()` can be rewritten as

```
bool comp(int a, int b)
{
    return ( a >= 0 && b < 0 );
}
```

but the problem is, that `std::sort()` doesn't guarantee that it will preserve the order of elements considered equal. Use `std::stable_sort()` instead.